# SQL query error of creating and inserting a table at the same time

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I have SQL query that need to do some calculation by a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO db.my_new_table 
SELECT db.table1.id  ,  db.table1.value  *  db.table2.factor  AS myValue 
FROM
 (
      SELECT a.id, SUM(a.value) AS factor
      FROM  db.table0  a
      GROUP by a.id
 ) AS table1
 JOIN  db.table2   AS  b
 ON db.table1.id  =  b.id;
```

But, I got error:

```
  ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command
```

I do not want to create a new table at first before running the query on db. 
I have access to db.
I want to do creating and inserting at the same time.

Thanks !

Comment: Does this explain the error you are getting and the workaround?  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.nz.dbu.doc%2Fc_dbuser_common_error_messages.html

Comment: @Steve Wellens, The same error, but, I am trying to insert table into the current database that I am logged in to. Thanks !

Comment: I've no experience with Netezza, but I wonder if it's worth playing with a derived table - if you can arrange things to the point where you get success with a derived table like : `SELECT derived.* FROM (SELECT ... your query ...) as derived` then you might stand a chance to add on the the `INSERT` in front of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your column references. You do not need to prefix columns with the schema, just with the alias. Also, your subquery does not have the field "value"; I think you may have transposed fields. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO db.my_new_table 
SELECT a.id, 
    a.factor * b.value AS myValue 
FROM (
        SELECT id, SUM(value) AS factor
        FROM  db.table0
        GROUP by id
     ) AS a
JOIN db.table2 AS b
     ON a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is truly that you don't have a table and want to create it as part of the insert statement, just change your insert to `CREATE TABLE db.my_new_table AS SELECT ....`

See the docs here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.nz.dbu.doc%2Fr_dbuser_create_table_as.html